# Dill dump_session: Making Jupyter-session pickle-able again

Tags: python, global, jupyter-lab, dill

I like to use dill.dump_session to save my notebook state.
However, I often have unpicklable objects loaded (dask-clusters, keras models).
Is there any way I can remove them from my environment and then use dump_session()?

I tried to find the offending object with dill.detect.errors:

(with globals() and locals() )

```
problemDict={}
exceptions=["Out","get_ipython","exit","quit"]

for name, obj in globals().items():
    if name in exceptions or name[0]=="_"::
        continue
    if dill.detect.errors(obj) is not None:
        print(name)
        problemDict[name]=obj
```

I deleted the two offending objects (and the summary dict afterwards) with

```
for name, obj in problemDict.items():
    print(name)
    del(globals()[name])
```

and they are gone form my namespace, but I still get the same error:

> TypeError: cannot pickle 'tensorflow.python._tf_stack.StackSummary' object

Could the keras-model still "hide" somewhere? Do the imports already make the session unpicklable?
Unfortunately, the dill.dump_session source code does not really help me much.
(https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_dill.py#L343)

Edit: the "dill.detect.trace(False)"-output did also not help. No idea what to do with:

```
...
# T4
2021-04-14 14:12:34,726 # T4
# D2
2021-04-14 14:12:34,727 # D2
# D2
2021-04-14 14:12:34,728 # D2
D2: <dict object at 0x7ffa9030a6c0>
2021-04-14 14:12:34,728 D2: <dict object at 0x7ffa9030a6c0>
D2: <dict object at 0x7ffa90305b80>
2021-04-14 14:12:34,736 D2: <dict object at 0x7ffa90305b80>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  Very good question.  Indeed if you delete the offending objects from globals and locals, they still can exist through pointer references.  You actually need to delete all references to the objects to have them gone.  This is something that I've intended to add to `dill`, but haven't yet.  There's some tools for reference tracing in `dill.pointers`.  The output from `dill.detect.trace` shows you the path `dill` is taking as it recursively follows references and serializes objects that are required to build the object that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the ...pointers ;-). It seems Jupyter/Ipython keeps some variables in "Out"/"_oh" and some temporary variables ("_[Number]") that I have not managed to root out yet and keep popping up after deleting globals. Will try more next week.

Answer (score 1):

While the original notebook is long closed (could not solve it), I had a similar issue.
Again, some variable was not pickable, and seemed to reside in some ipython variable after `del`.
Manually deleting "Out"/"_oh"-keys/items did not help, but

```
%reset out
```

made the session finally pickable again!

God, I really hope this was the underlying problem...